# SQL single column split over multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to split the single column result from a query into 4 columns:

Sample source:  (`Select [FirstName from User`)
Peter
Mary
John
Tina
Carl
Jane
Bill
Sarah

I want to look like this:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4  
Peter     Mary      John      Tina  
Carl      Jane      Bill      Sarah
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a unique column to `ORDER BY` to get deterministic results but something along these lines should work.

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT [FirstName],
                ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 ) / 4 AS Row,
                ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 ) % 4 AS Col
         FROM   [User])
SELECT [0] AS Column1,
       [1] AS Column2,
       [2] AS Column3,
       [3] AS Column4
FROM   T PIVOT (MAX(name) FOR Col IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])) P 
ORDER BY Row
```

Comment: Thank you! I did get it working using 4 temp tables with differing Modulus  and joining on rownums, but the CTE looks nicer!

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - True, or the aliasing needs changed as it outputs `1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0`. Edited as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have tons of options, look for the one is more suited for your case:
[Create columns from list of values](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.es/2009/10/making-list-and-checking-it-twice.html)

Previous link directs to [even more information](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.es/2009/10/un-making-list-or-shredding-of-evidence.html)

Comment: I had a look at the link, but it only shows how to build a single column containing multiple rows' values. I want to break down 1 column into 4 columns

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just edited my answer, maybe it should be a comment and not a full answer as the provided links give you lot of info but not the exact answer to your question.